# How do I change the scope of an object?

Tags: esp8266, mqtt

I am using the File/Examples/Adafruit MQTT Library/mqtt_ESP8266 example as a model for my code.  In the example, the mqtt object is created as a global variable, and everything works fine.  However, I need to create the mqtt object in setup(), because the constructor parameters are not known until then.  If I move the constructor call

```
Adafruit_MQTT_Client mqtt(&client, AIO_SERVER, AIO_SERVERPORT, AIO_USERNAME, AIO_KEY);
```

from the global namespace to inside setup(), I can no longer see it from inside loop().

I have tried declaring a pointer to mqtt in the global namespace, but don't know how to change it to point to the mqtt object that is created in setup().  How can I do this?

David

Answer (score 1):

In general there is several ways to do it, none of them is the perfect one...

1. pointer to mqtt at global scope `Adafruit_MQTT_Client * mqtt_ptr;` and initialize it by `mqtt_ptr = new Adafruit_MQTT_Client(&client, AIO_SERVER, AIO_SERVERPORT, AIO_USERNAME, AIO_KEY);` in setup. Then you have to use arrow operator instead dot to access its methods. Or you can make an alias in loop (or whenever you need it) by `Adafruit_MQTT_Client& mqtt = *mqtt_ptr;` and access it in the same way as before.
2. returning reference to static variable created inside of function (singleton), but you have to provide parameters every time, even they're needed only for the first time. The static variable gets constructed only for the first call of function.
3. For esp8266 there might be available `std::optional` template. It's similar to pointer, but you don't have to use arrow `->` operator. But there might be extraneous copy when you assign (create) it's value.
4. You can also extend 1. or 2. by own class to hold parameters and then return instance of `Adafruit_MQTT_Client`